# Не могу убрать ошибку

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

[image: код]

[image: ошибка]

Не понимаю, почему происходит ошибка
Как работает sys.path.appendend

views.py находится в C:\django\project\firstapp\views.py
а urls.py в C:\django\project\hello

Как убрать ошибку не перенося файлы?

Comment: Что-то у вас всё напутано. По джанговой задумке firstapp должен быть python-модулем и django-приложением, и оба файла views.py и urls.py должны быть внутри firstapp, и никаких sys.path.append не надо

Answer (score 0):

Вместо

```
from firstapp import views
```

напишите просто

```
import views
```

т.к. `views` не является функцией или классом (и `firstapp` нет модулем).

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь из папки `firstapp` импортировать `firstapp`. Добавляйте путь ДО папки, а не вместе с ней.

У вас:

`sys.path.append('C:/django/hello/firstapp')`

Должно быть:

`sys.path.append('C:/django/hello')`